# Why is PyQt application startup so slow?

Tags: python, performance, pyqt, startup

C++ is fast. Qt is fast. Python interpreter startup is relatively fast (2-3 seconds on my computer). PyQt is thin wrapper around Qt. Why then PyQt app startup (about 80 lines, even in .pyc form) is so slow (6-12 seconds)? I'm interested in reasons for this and, most importantly, ways to improve this situation.

Comment: Which version of `Qt` are you using? Do you run Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows, Qt 4.4.3, PyQt 4.7.3, Python 3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [a known bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-11309) in Qt 4.6.3 that cripples application start times. Maybe 4.4.3 is also affected. Try to upgrade to 4.7.0, which fixes that bug.

Your problem might also come from [dynamic library relocation](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/dynamic-linking-linux-and-windows-part-two). If you compile either Qt or Python yourself, try to give them a base address different from the default (0x10000000), to prevent relocation to occur when the two libraries are loaded together.

Under Linux, you could have used [prelink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink), but to my knowledge it has no equivalent on Windows.